# Getting help recursive C programming

Tags: c, recursion, subsequence

Given an **array** of length `n`, and the requirement is to write the program to **calculate** the ***number of sub-sequences*** of length `m` of that given array.

Below is the code to do it. Please, have a look.

```
int recCountSubseq(int seqLength, int length, int s[]) {
    int answer;

    if (seqLength == 0) {       /* Base case: found a subseq of correct length */
        return 1;
    }

    if (seqLength >= length) {  /* Base case: only possible is seqLength == length*/
        return (seqLength==length);
    }

    /* Recursive case: two branches */
    answer = recCountSubseq(seqLength-1, length-1, s); /* s[length-1] is in subseq*/
    printf("answer=%d\n", answer);

    answer += recCountSubseq(seqLength, length-1, s);  /* s[length-1] is not in subseq */
    printf("increased answer is %d\n", answer);

    return answer;
}

void countSubseq(int seqLength, int length, int s[]) {    
    printf("#subseq = %d\n", recCountSubseq(seqLength, length, s));    
}

int main() {
    int length;
    scanf("%d", &length);

    int seqLength;
    int i;
    int s[100];

    for (i=0;i<length; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &s[i]);
    }

    countSubseq(seqLength, length, s);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Now, **my question:** Why is the value of `seqLength` decreasing each time, and how exactly is this code working ?

Comment: In you case, `seqLength` must eventually be `0` so the recursive calling of `recCountSubseq` ceases.

Comment: `seqLength` has not been initialized. Code is broken and cannot be reasoned with.

Comment: if u try to compile it works and gives the number of ellements in the array as I found but I dont understand why the seqLength is decreasing

Comment: What is your program supposed to do ? What is your input and expected output ?

Comment: To be honest michael I didnt get this point, when I run I found that it just gives me number of ellements in the array. but I am not sure how comes.

Comment: This is my question what u asked ))

Answer (score 2):

The function has undefined behaviour because at least variable `seqLength` was not initialized:

```
int seqLength;
```

And the task is not clear. If you have an array with `n` elements then the number of continious subsequencies of length `m` where `m <= n` is equal to `n - m + 1`.

So writing such a function does not make great sense.:) Moreover I do not see even where in the function there is an access to the array passed as the third argument.:)

Insetad I can suggest you the following function. At least it has some sense.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t recCountSubseq( const int a[], size_t n, size_t m )
{
    if ( m <= n )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return n <= m ? n == m : 1 + recCountSubseq( ++a, --n, m );
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    printf( "There are %zu subsequencies\n", recCountSubseq( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), 3 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 
2 3 4 
3 4 5 
4 5 6 
5 6 7 
6 7 8 
7 8 9 
There are 7 subsequencies
```

I think you are incorrectly interpretating the assignment and its solution. You should check their descriptions anew.

Comment: I was thinking the same, this is code from my professor and actually it works and I dont know how in the beginning the seqLength is getting the length. This I dont understand and it also causes vague why it decreases

Comment: @NatiaEbralidze As for I do not entirely understand what the code does.:)  Could you describe the purpose of the function?

Comment: @NatiaEbralidze Are you Georgian?:)

Comment: I will try. I was asked to write the function that computes the number of subsequences with length m from an array with a given length n. so in the function this "m" is seqLength, and "n" is length of original array. is it clear? (the main what code has to do is to give number of subsequences with a given length)

Comment: @NatiaEbralidze update your question and don't put half of the question in some comment.

Comment: @NatiaEbralidze I showed a silly function that recursively outputs subsequencies of the given size and returns the number of them. But I am sure it is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need to get from the user the length of the sub-sequence, which is not being done in your code.

If my guess is correct, then the main() function would look like this:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
  int length;

  printf("Length of array:");
  scanf("%d", &length);

  int seqLength;

  printf("Length of sub-seq:");
  scanf("%d", &seqLength);

  int i;
  int s[100];

  printf("Array of %d elements:", length);
  for (i=0;i<length; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &s[i]);
  }

  countSubseq(seqLength, length, s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you task is to write a function that "computes the number of subsequences with length m from an array with a given length n" than you must tell your function what are *m* and *n*. You're already getting *n* (length) and you should get *m* (seqLength) as well

Comment: what u say it has to be given by the progam. I am not sure dear. I really dont get the question I guess

Comment: I tried to run as u said and it still gives me the same answer as before without giving the length of the subLength

Comment: Your input arguments would be: 
*n - length of array* and *m - length os sub-sequences*

And your **output** would not be a variable (in the code you pasted), but rather would be printed in the screen "#subseq = XX"